# Create STEP/IGES or whatever file from .NET

Tags: .net, 3d, autocad, step

From my application (.NET 2.0 c#) I need to export a 3D object to a file importable in AutoCAD.
I created my DirectX 9 Mesh and I show it in a DirectX control, but with SlimDX I am not able to create a .X file, that anywhay can not be imported directly in AutoCAD, and I can not run and external conversione tool, well, I can, but the final user not.

STEP or IGES files would be the best option

SlimDX is needed because I need both 32 and 64 support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AutoCAD Inventor implementation coverage of STEP does not include Mesh (Tessellated) in STEP.
http://www.cax-if.org/vendor_info.php?file_id=2&comp_id=8
Meshlab may be useful to convert from your mesh format to a mesh format that Inventor can import like STL.